# Disable URL checks in CSS in angular application (ng build). Like in libraries (ng build some-lib)

Tags: angular

I created an Angular application using `ng new my-application` command. Also I created a library in this application using `ng generate library my-lib`.

Here is a simple CSS code with background-image property. The image file does not exist

```
.class1 {
  background-image: url('./not-existing-file.png');
}
```

If I put this CSS code in the library `projects/my-lib/src/lib/my-lib.component.scss` and run `ng build my-lib` then the library will build successfully.

But if I put this CSS code in the src folder `src/app/app.component.scss` and run `ng build` then I get error:

```
NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: C:\app.component.scss:2:2: Can't resolve '../not-existing-file.png' in 'C:\angular-tour-of-heroes\src\app'
```

I need to disable URL checks in CSS in `ng build` command, like in `ng build my-lib`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable [`url(...)` processing](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#url) in your css-loader plugin (which again requires using an external web pack config). Basically do the following in your web-pack config.

`{loader: 'css-loader', options: {url: false}}`

But I suggest inlining the images in your library only. That way during compilation your image path would be replaced with [data uris](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/). You just have to set  `"cssUrl": "inline"` in your libraries `ng-package.json` to make this working.

```
{
  "$schema": "../../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "lib": {
    "cssUrl": "inline",
  }
}
```